# ExtJS 6 - Grid with colorbutton on widgetcolumn - click event goes to the controller

Tags: extjs

I can use the `colorbutton` in a toolbar, for example. When I click on it, the click event shows the color picker.

But I would like to have it inside a grid, to configure the color for each element of the grid.

I've added a column to the grid with:

```js
            {
                xtype: "widgetcolumn",
                width: 60,
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'colorbutton'
                }
            }
```

**The problem is the event on the grid.** It requires a callback `onClick` on the controller. The click event goes to the controller, not to the `colorbutton`.

I would like to trigger the `onClick` event of the `colorbutton` to display the picker.

In the image below, is my grid. Clicking on the button on the grid does not workm while clicking on the toolbar works fine, as expected.

[image]

Documentation: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/components/widgets_widgets_columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use template column to represent the color. Something like this:

```
...
columns: [{
...
...
}, {
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    text: "Template Color Column",
    flex: 1,
    dataIndex: 'color',
    tpl: '<div style="background-color: #{color}; border: 1px solid #99bce8; width: 16px; height: 16px;"></div>',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'colorfield',
        listeners: {
            focus: function (field) {
                field.expand();
            }
        }
    }
}, {
...
...
}],
...
```

Or you can use [custom color column](http://www.coding-ideas.de/2020/06/27/grid-color-column/).

Comment: Artur, I've forked your fiddle (thank you!) and added my alternative to show the difference (just regarding the usability). The forked fiddle is at: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3707

Comment: I have refactored the fiddle sample.. moved separated the store, model..

Answer (score 1):

The anwer provided by Arthur Rubens solves the problem.

I've ended up with similar solution, using a `widgetcolumn`. Editing th field with this alternative approach is smoother (less one click and the user never sees the combobox).

Ths print screen includes the two solutions. For the Background 1 column, I used Arthur's solution, based on a `templatecolumn`.

[image]

For this alternative solution, I used the following code:

```js
, {
            text: 'Background 2',
            xtype: "widgetcolumn",
            width: 120,
            dataIndex: 'color',
            widget: {
                xtype: 'colorfield',
                hideTrigger: true,
                bind: '{record.color}',
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: 'afterrenderColorPickerField'
                }
            }
        },
```

And in the controller:

```js
    afterrenderColorPickerField: function (color_picker_field) {
        // console.log('afterrenderColorPickerField');
        if (color_picker_field.inputEl && color_picker_field.inputEl.dom) {
            color_picker_field.inputEl.dom.style.backgroundColor = "#" + color_picker_field.getValue();
            color_picker_field.inputEl.dom.style.color = "#" + color_picker_field.getValue();
        }
        color_picker_field.addListener('change', this.colorChanged, this);
    },

    colorChanged: function (color_picker_field, new_value, old_value) {
        // console.log('colorChanged to ' + new_value);
        // var record = color_picker_field.getWidgetRecord();
        // record.set('style', new_value);
        if (color_picker_field.inputEl && color_picker_field.inputEl.dom) {
            color_picker_field.inputEl.dom.style.backgroundColor = "#" + new_value;
            color_picker_field.inputEl.dom.style.color = "#" + new_value;
        }
    },
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3707) available, based on Arthur's fiddle.